# XML file download blocked in selenium chromedriver

Tags: xml, selenium-chromedriver, blocked

I am trying to export data from excel in an application which exports XML file as default. When I click the export button it opens a new chrome window & it has a warning message "This file can harm your computer" with options Keep Or Discard.
I want XML files to be downloaded automatically without this prompt. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be controlled via chromeoptions.

`--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`

In Java,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Check here for more info.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: This did not work. I still see the warning message. I also tried driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
Actions act = new Actions(driver);            act.SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Perform();
act.SendKeys(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")),Keys.Enter).Perform();

Comment: Hi @vins using options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled","false"); did the trick. Thanks for the heads up.